# Brace expansion doesn't work the way I expect

Tags: bash

I wonder why doesn't my command work the way I expect?

Here is my command:

```
touch resources/views/front/user/{index, show, create, edit}.blade.php
```

What I expect is to create 4 files in that path but instead it does create one file with name {index,

Answer (score 5):

In a word - *whitespace*:

```
$ echo {index, show, create, edit}.blade.php
{index, show, create, edit}.blade.php
```

but

```
$ echo {index,show,create,edit}.blade.php
index.blade.php show.blade.php create.blade.php edit.blade.php
```